# How can I determine if game is playable with a controller?

Tags: pc, controllers

I never played games with a controllers, but I just recently got a wireless PC one, so I might give it a shot. However, I'm not sure which games will I be able to play with it! Is there a centralized source of information, or am I supposed to browse gaming forums/ask people to find out?

Comment: I've always just googled "<game name> xbox 360 controller" and found what I needed from that search

Comment: Even if it isn't controller enabled, xPadder is a free program that allows you to configure each button for PC controls, and separate files for each game can be made.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use Steam there is a "Controller Enabled" graphic displayed in the right column near the bottom of the game page in the store.  Also here you will find out what Steam features it supports like Cloud Saves or Achievements.

[image: "Controller enabled" graphic in Steam]

If the game you're interested in isn't on Steam, then check to see if there is an Xbox 360 version of the game.  In my experience those usually leave the controller option available on the PC, however; its not a guarantee.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of a game that has that graphic? For example, Skyrim doesn't, but it was designed to be played with a controller.

Comment: Found them, CS:GO, for one, and Rochard.

Comment: Sorry, I was going to include the graphic but I didn't have enough reputation at the time to add it.  [Half-minute Hero](http://store.steampowered.com/app/214830/) includes one.

Answer (score 6):

When a controller is not an option, you can use one of many programs that will map controller buttons to keyboard actions.  This will allow you to use your controller for multiple games that might not otherwise support a controller.

Your wireless controller (you did not specific a brand) may come with a program that already allows you to do this.  Here is another option I found after a quick search:

http://www.racketboy.com/retro/xpadder-use-your-pc-gamepad-instead-of-keyboard

... you just need to get past the absolute HORROR of the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can also hit the "Big Picture Mode" on steam and it allows you to control Steam directly with the Xbox controller. It then shows a little controller icon next to game compatible with it and a keyboard for non-compatible games.