# Is there a way to view controller support from my Library?

Tags: steam

Some Steam games offer full controller support, some offer only partial support, and some do not offer any support. What I want is a quick way to tell which of the games *in my Library* have some form of controller support. I recently got a gamepad and I'm wondering which games I should install to try it out.

The only way I've found so far is to go to each game's page and scroll all the way down to one of the panels on the right. Hardly a quick and easy process when you have a ton of games.

If I recall correctly, there is better information on this when in Big Picture mode, but only when you hover over/select a game in the list. I also don't generally use Big Picture mode as I play on my monitor.

Is there a way to quickly see which games from my entire library have some form of controller support? Some filter or setting I haven't found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently a way to filter on Controller Support in Library mode by using the Advanced Filtering dialog:

[image: Steam Library Advanced Filtering for Controller Support]

Answer (score 21):

Yes there is, but it needs to be done within Steam Big Picture mode. Start Big Picture mode and then navigate through the menus as follows;

- Select 'Library'
- Select 'View all Games'
- From the drop down menu select 'Controller Supported'

[image]

This will list all games you have licenses for on your Steam account, and you can download them from this screen also.

Comment: Accepted as there doesn't seem to be a way to do it outside of Big Picture Mode

Comment: This does not apply to the Mac version of Steam.

Comment: This answer still works (July 2017) but the drop down menu has been moved to the right of the games list, a button labelled "Filter Games".

Comment: @yusf it does today.

Comment: There is now a quick and easy way to do this in the Library, see my full answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Lorenzo's tool will allow you to filter your entire Steam library by tag, including full or partial controller support. Your Steam profile/library must be public for the tool to successfully scan your games.

http://www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/steam/

Comment: Just checked this website out, afraid it might be a phishing website. Works great! Just enter your username and it will list the games you have, no need to "log in" or enter your password.

Comment: @s1h4d0w Out of interest, what makes you think it's a phishing website? If it just uses your username, presumably it's just querying the Steam user database for the games linked to that account (same as when you visit someone's profile). However, if you have good reason to believe it may be malicious we should remove the link.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it does as I explained in my comment. But whenever I see a link posted to a site claiming to be able to look into your account I wonder if it asks for login data and might lure unsuspecting visitors into giving away their credentials. I simply wanted to put a disclaimer.

Answer (score 3):

3rd party service [Steam Database](http://steamdb.info) is able to filter for

- [Partial Controller Support](https://steamdb.info/myapps/?category=18)
- [Full controller support](https://steamdb.info/myapps/?category=28)
- [Native Steam Controller](https://steamdb.info/myapps/?category=33) support

Once you give SteamDB access to your account you may view these lists.

Comment: Looks useful, but I'm wary of handing over my login details to a third party. The FAQ doesn't say anything about how they use/store the details, either, unless I missed it. Do you have any more info on how safe/reliable this is?

Comment: Zero info. I believe you may view some of the information transferred during authorization.

Comment: SteamDB is trusted by me at least, I use it frequently along with Steam companion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can outside of Big Picture Mode. Answered here, [StackOverFlow: How Can I Determine If Game Is Playabe With A Controller](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86509/how-can-i-determine-if-game-is-playable-with-a-controller) and I can confirm it still works, [Skyrim](http://store.steampowered.com/app/72850/) offers partial support.

Comment: He literally mentions this method in the question. He was looking for a quicker way.

Comment: And he also literally says in a comment on the accepted answer, "there doesn't seem to be a way to do it outside of Big Picture Mode." I was just reiterating that it still works outside of Big Picture Mode.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a way to do that in Steam in normal mode. However, if your game-list is publicly visible/viewable you can use [MySteamGauge](http://www.mysteamgauge.com/) to list all your games and sort them by controller support (none, partial, full and "-" ??).

No additional credentials/authentication required.
I just tried a [*random*](http://www.mysteamgauge.com/account?username=racerx) username and it works.

I guess it's kind of comparable to www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/steam/ which was mentioned by Castaa in his [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/257863/178093).

Comment: @Vemonus - I assume / my guess is that www.MySteamGauge.com and www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/steam/ both use publicly available information from a [Steam-account](https://steamcommunity.com/id/racerX/) to show specific information in a more useful way.

Comment: I don't know what you want. In the past i sometimes used MySteamGauge and I've never used www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/steam/  but if i compare both sites I see similar information displayed/organized in a different way.

Comment: The answer seemed questionable so I was getting more details. I didn't realize the site came from another answer. Thank you for clarifying

Comment: I forgot to make that clear beforehand and added the reference to @Castaa in my answer after reading your first comment.